# How to extract multiple columns from a csv file with ruby?

Tags: ruby

Right now I can extract 1 column (column 6) from the csv file. How could I edit the script below to extract more than 1 column? Let's say I also want to extract column 9 and 10 as well as 6. I would want the output to be such that column 6 ends up in column 1 of the output file, 9 in the 2nd column of the output file, and column 10 in the 3rd column of the output file.

```
ruby -rcsv -e 'CSV.foreach(ARGV.shift) {|row| puts row [5]}' input.csv &> output.csv
```

Comment: Create a normal script that reads fro a file and writes to another file instead of shell oneliner, otherwise you’ll experience issues with escaping quotes, commas etc.

Comment: Unrelated answer, but maybe useful to you: If your file has headers, you should be able to pass in a `headers: true` argument and then specify the columns you want rather than their index `row[:first_name],row[:last_name]` etc.

Answer (score 2):

Since `row` is an array, your question boils down to how to pick certain elements from an array; this is not related to CSV.

You can use [values_at](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-values_at):

```
row.values_at(5,6,9,10)
```

returns the fields 5,6,9 and 10.

If you want to present these picked fields in a different order, it is however easier to map each index explicitly:

```
output_row = Array.new(row.size) # Or row.dup, depending on your needs
output_row[1] = row[6]
# Or, if you have used row.dup and want to swap the rows:
output_row[1],output_row[6] = row[6],row[1]
# and so on
out_csv.puts(output_row)
```

This assumes that you have defined before

```
out_csv=CSV.new(STDOUT)
```

since you want to have your new CSV be created on standard output.

Answer (score 1):

Let's first create a (header-less) CSV file:

```
enum = 1.step
FNameIn = 't_in.csv'

CSV.open(FNameIn, "wb") { |csv| 3.times { csv << 5.times.map { enum.next } } }
  #=> 3
```

I've assumed the file contains string representations of integers.

The file contains the three lines:

```
File.read(FNameIn).each_line { |line| p line }
"1,2,3,4,5\n"
"6,7,8,9,10\n"
"11,12,13,14,15\n"
```

Now let's extract the columns at indices `1` and `3`. These columns are to be written to the output file in that order.

```
cols = [1, 3]
```

Now write to the CSV output file.

```
arr = CSV.read(FNameIn, converters: :integer).
          map { |row| row.values_at(*cols) }
  #=> [[2, 4], [7, 9], [12, 14]] 

FNameOut = 't_out.csv'
CSV.open(FNameOut, 'wb') { |csv| arr.each { |row| csv << row } }
```

We have written three lines:

```
File.read(FNameOut).each_line { |line| p line }
"2,4\n"
"7,9\n"
"12,14\n"
```

which we can read back into an array:

```
CSV.read(FNameOut, converters: :integer)
  #=> [[2, 4], [7, 9], [12, 14]]
```

A straightforward transformation of these operations is required to perform these operations from the command line.